# Not found neither logback.xml nor log4j.properties in spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j, logback, slf4j

I would like to implement MDC in my microservice. To do the configuration changes, I am unable to find the logback.xml or log4j.properties in my spring boot app resources folder
,
[image: Resources folder in project structure]

Could any one one help me here , How the logging may implemented here?

Answer (score 0):

The file should be available from your `src/resources` (put it right next to application.properties).